# Solve $4 \log_2 (n) \leq \frac{n}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have to find the $n \in \mathbb{N}$ whenever $4 \log_2 (n) \leq \frac{n}{2}$. So

$$4 \log_2 (n) \leq \frac{n}{2}$$
$$ \iff \log_2 (n) \leq \frac{n}{8}$$
$$ \iff \frac{1}{n}\log_2 (n) \leq \frac{1}{8}$$
$$ \iff \log_2 (n^\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{8}$$
$$ \iff n^\frac{1}{n} \leq 2^\frac{1}{8}$$

I am not sure how I can use that to find the appropriate $n$. Is there a better technique to find the right $n$?

**EDIT**

Not sure I can use induction here. I have to find the minimum $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ where $4 \log_2 (n) \leq \frac{n}{2}$ for $n \geq n_0$. How to find that $n_0$?

[image]

Comment: Well, which side intuitively grows faster?

Comment: @JoshuaWang n/2 will grow faster

Comment: Ok, so since each function is concave all $n$ past a certain point should satisfy your inequality, right? Use induction to prove this.

Comment: I can't use induction, because I have to find the $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ where $4 \log_2 (n) \leq \frac{n}{2}$ for $n \geq n_0$. How to find that $n_0$? This is the question

Comment: Use a table or graphing software to find when $\frac n2-4\log_2(n)\geq0$.

Comment: I assume you're looking for an analytical answer? $n^{1/n}$ is decreasing with limit zero, so you know by definition of limit that, for some natural $n_0$, all $n>n_0$ imply the inequality in question. I don't think induction is necessary. I'd find that $n_0$ numerically or graphically. But if you want to determine $n_0$ analitically, well that's an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

As a real, the solution of $$4 \log_2 (n) = \frac{n}{2}$$ is given in terms of Lambert function
$$n=-\frac{8 }{\log (2)}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)\sim 43.5593$$ so $\lceil n \rceil=44$.

Checking
$$4 \log_2 (43) - \frac{43}{2} \sim +0.205059$$
$$4 \log_2 (44) - \frac{44}{2} \sim -0.162274$$

**Edit**

If you do not know about Lambert function (or if you cannot use it), consider the function and derivatives
$$f(n)=\frac{4 \log (n)}{\log (2)}-\frac{n}{2}$$
$$f'(n)=\frac{4}{n \log (2)}-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$f''(n)=-\frac{4}{n^2 \log (2)} \quad < 0 \quad \forall n$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$n_*=\frac{8}{\log (2)}\implies f(n_*)=-\frac{4 \left(1+\log \left(\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)\right)}{\log (2)} <0$$ Develop $f(n)$ as a Taylor series around $n_*$ to get
$$f(n)=f(n_*)+\frac 1 2 f''(n_*)(n-n_*)^2+O((n-n_*)^3$$
Solve the quadratic to get a starting point
$$n_0=n_*+\sqrt{-2\frac{f(n_*)}{f''(n_*)}}\sim 31.1687$$ Now, start Newton method and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n_k \\
 0 & 31.1687 \\
 1 & 44.7107 \\
 2 & 43.5645 \\
 3 & 43.5593
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Doubling this answer, I followed the same work and came back to see someone else answered with it.

Comment: Yes this is the way. Does the OP know about Lambert functions or how to derive that formula though?

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

You can use the fact that $2^{x}$ is an increasing function.

$$8log_{2}(n)\leq n$$

whenever

$$2^{8log_{2}(n)} \leq 2^{n} $$

simplifying

$$n^{8} \leq 2^{n} $$

Whenever

$$0 \leq 2^{n} - n^{8} $$

Either solve the equation 2^{x} - x^{8} = 0 and take the next largest integer value which follows the largest solution. If this is within the methods and techniques that you have been taught. The solution looks quite messy so it may be too complex in your course to find the exact value of such x.

Otherwise try solutions of the form $n=2^{k}$ find the first such $k > 0$ which satisfies the inequality, which is $k=6$ and you can look for $2^{5}=32<n<64=2^{6}$. Plotting the graph also helps narrow down where to look.

$n=44$ is the first such value.

Maybe there is some slick way to finish the computation that I am missing.

Comment: I know all that already. You would need to add some more details

Comment: One more way you could expand 2n is using binomial expansion
$2^n=(1+1)^n=1+n+\frac{n(n−1)}{2}+\frac{n(n−1)(n−2)}{6}...$ possibly up to 8 terms and see if you could get anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Iterate: $$k_0=1, k_{n+1}=8\log_2(k_n)\implies \lim_{j\to\infty} k_j\approx 43.55926044$$